# Remove leaves from a binary tree using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I tried to do this using this logic but I am getting error

```
public static void removeLeaves(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> temp = root;   
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        root = null;
    }

    removeLeaves(temp.left);
    removeLeaves(temp.right);
}
```

Whole tree is getting printed as it is. Please help me out without changing my logic.

Comment: If the logic is flawed it makes it hard to suggest a correction if we aren't allowed to change the logic. Just thought I'd point that out in case you meant something different.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement

```
if(root.left==null && root.right==null)
{
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> temp = null;
    root = temp;
}
```

You are declaring root as temp, which is null, then pass that temp into the `removeLeaves` function. So you are passing null into that function when the if statement is true.

Comment: can you suggest me a solution for my problem without changing much of my logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
BinaryTreeNode<Integer> temp = null;
root = temp;
```

basically sets `root` to `null` and then you call `root.left` => NPE

You might want to add the necessarily null checks, and probably rethink your function as a whole.

Comment: can you suggest me a solution for my problem without changing much of my logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each root individually for null. Your if statement

```
    if(root.left==null && root.right==null)
    {
       BinaryTreeNode<Integer> temp = null;
       root = temp;
    }
```

only checks if both roots are null. But say there is no left leaf (root.left is null) and there is only a right leaf, you still execute on the left side

```
    removeLeaves(root.left);
```

However, we already know that root.left is null. I suggest adding individual checks before each call to removeLeaves() or modifying your existing if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced this isn't a homework assignment, but here goes.

The null exception is because you are still calling removeLeaves() even when both the left and right sides are null.  Have you tried putting an else after your main IF()?

```
public static void removeLeaves(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root)
{
    if(root == null)  
    {
        return; // enclosing conditionals in braces is better form, saves lots of headaches later
    }


    if(root.left==null && root.right==null)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<Integer> temp = null;
        root = temp;
    }
    else //at least one is not null
    {
        removeLeaves(root.left);
        removeLeaves(root.right);
    }
}
```